# Caching a Map in Java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, caching

I am writing a methodA() which returns a Map<String, String> by accessing an object in Amazon S3 and this method will be called several times (in the order of thousands) every hour. I want to get the object from S3 every day (and not for every method call) and maintain this map in a local cache for all the method calls. What should my approach be ?

Comment: Are you caching it for one instance of a long-running application?  Or maybe for multiple applications or multiple runs of the same application? Will the cached object be modified, and if so, how far do the changes need to propagate?  Must the cache support concurrent access from multiple applications?

Comment: The cached object will not be modified. I haven't started caching it yet but my initial question is should i be caching that map instead of fetching it everytime from S3. Sorry if the question is not too clear.

Comment: It's not so much that the question is unclear, but that it is lacking in essential detail and is very open-ended.  And you're opening it up even further by adding "should I cache?" to the original "how should I cache?"  SO questions are not for soliciting discussion.

Comment: your approach is `guava` `LoadingCache` with an eviction policy that works once a day. Or caffeine, which has the same capabilities.

Comment: thanks Eugene! Just implemented it using LoadingCache and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

A map can solve this issue but you also have to make sure to evict your cache if necessary.

If you more than one instance of your application you should maybe think about a shared cache i.e. a redis database.